# How to remove unplugged device from lsusb's result

Tags: usb, lsusb

I put the USB wlan NIC into my server.
However it did not work correctly, I pull it off.
But it still remains the lsusb's result.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04bb:0948 I-O Data Device, Inc. WN-G300U Wireless LAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`148f:5370 Ralink Technology` is the removed one.

**How can I remove that bogus interface?**

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64).

** additional info ***

```
$ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/

1-0:1.0/   1-1.6/     1-1:1.0/   2-1/       3-0:1.0/   usb1/      usb3/
1-1/       1-1.6:1.0/ 2-0:1.0/   2-1:1.0/   4-0:1.0/   usb2/      usb4/
```

Comment: could you please post output of `cat /proc/bus/usb/devices` ?

Comment: From Kernel 3.6(?), /proc/bus/usb moved to /sys/bus/usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`USBdetach`](https://github.com/Lefinnois/USBdetach) :

```
./usbdetach -v -p /dev/ttyUSBx
```

There is brief explanation given on [this](http://pvbookmarks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devel/drivers/usb/usb_tools/linux/usbdetach/) blog you can refer to that page for more information.

Comment: Blog link gives a 404 error.